# View commits (and diff) pertaining to a particular git branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff, git-log

Suppose I have the following git structure:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F master
         \_ G - H - I branch
```

`git checkout branch; git log` doesn't identify the point at which branch diverged from master.

What if I want to examine all changes in this branch?

Answer (score 5):

You correctly found `git log master..branch`

To also get `C` (the fork point itself) listed, try :

```
git log --boundary master..branch
```

---

If you want the diff between `C` and `I`, that would be :

```
git diff master...branch  # three dots
```

which is a shortcut for :

```
git diff $(git merge-base master branch) branch
```

---

*extra notes for `git log`* :

To have a clearer view of who is a parent of who, you can add `--graph` :

```
git log --graph --boundary master..branch
```

Combining it with `--oneline` gives you a (IMHO) good and compact overview of your history :

```
git log --oneline --graph --boundary master..branch
```

Comment: Note that `--boundary` sometimes (in complex graphs) finds "extra" boundary commits. I think this is a bug myself, although I'm pretty sure it is an artifact of the somewhat bizarre algorithms that Git uses internally.

Answer (score 2):

Surprised I couldn't easily find an answer to this one. It seems like a really common problem.

```
git log master..branch
```

... gets the commits for `G, H, I` (Does anyone know how to get `C, G, H, I`?)

But `git diff master..branch` gets `diff(F -> I)`.

You need:

```
git log -p master..branch`
```

... to get `diff(C -> I)`

Comment: Why do you need `C` if it's technically not an exclusive commit to `branch`?

Comment: _Does anyone know how to get `C, G, H, I`?_ -- `git log master~1..branch`?

Comment: @fluffy : that wouldn't work : `master~1` is `E`

Comment: @LeGEC Oops, sorry, yes, you're right. There is a typo in `C~1..branch` where `C` might be computed with `merge-base`. (However, I was not aware of `--boundary`, so +1)